Cancel calendar invite giving a reason/message as to why
In the Office365 web calendar, when I cancel a meeting I've scheduled I can add a message to explain why.
Does anyone know how to do this is the macOS native calendar app please? I can delete the event fine, but can't figure out any way to provide an explanation to attendees of why I'm cancelling at the same time like I can on the web.

Unfortunately, this feature is not available on Mac Mail.  It could be speculated that since Microsoft “grew up” in corporate whereas Macs are traditionally personal devices (maybe some small business), a feature like this is a natural outgrowth of Outlook as it evolves.
I know from personal experience that canceling a meeting of more than 10 people, attaching a cancellation message was critical.  Before this feature existed, I had to manually create an email message to send to attendees.
You should provide product feedback/new feature request to Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/calendar/
